# How to write text more than 10 letters using Canvas and paint on map?

Tags: android, google-maps, canvas, paint

Marking few markers and adding names using Canvas and Paint on map. But am able to see the text only 9 characters rest are hiding (not visible). How to do it?

```
private Bitmap drawTitleOnMarkerIcon(MarkingInfo markingInfo) {
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), AddLocationTypeIcon.getIcon(markingInfo.getType())).copy(
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
    paint.setTextSize(16);
    paint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
    canvas.drawText(markingInfo.getName(), 0, 60, paint);

    BitmapDrawable draw = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm);
    return draw.getBitmap();
}
```

I should able to see complete text, When I have more than 15 character just I need to wrap it to next line. search many sites and posted query previously but I got no solution. please do help to achieve this task

Comment: I need to add name near to marker which should visible always when map is opened, but your link is getting name in info window

Answer (score 0):

```
private Bitmap textAsBitmap(String text, float textSize, int textColor) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize(textSize);
paint.setColor(textColor);
    paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    int width = (int) (paint.measureText(text) + 0.5f); // round
    float baseline = (int) (-paint.ascent() + 0.5f); // ascent()is negative
    int height = (int) (baseline + paint.descent() + 0.5f);
Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
canvas.drawText(text, 0, baseline, paint);
    return image;
    }




MarkerOptions().title(Name()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(textAsBitmap));
```